# Problem error checking -match and IF statement

Tags: powershell, csv

The below script will import an exported CSV from our MIS system so that we can upload to google classroom.  In tern, this will allow bulk creation of classes with our custom classnames based on word matching within the regex.csv.

As you can see from the exporteddata.csv, 10552 is blank.

Is it possible for this to be omitted from the final export and added into its own errors.csv file?

Any help would be great!

Script.ps1

```
$data = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\data.csv" -Delimiter ','
$patterns = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\Regex\regex.csv" -Delimiter ','
$interimexportedData = "$PSScriptRoot\classesinterim.csv" 
$exportclasses = "$PSScriptRoot\exporteddata.csv" 

## Imports the initial SIMS export of classes and created a 'prefered' name for the class, then exports to a CSV.
$data | Select-Object *,@{Name='preference'; Expression={
  foreach ($p in $patterns) {
    if ($_.title -match $p.'regex_key') {
     $p.preference + " " + "-" + " " + $_.title
     return
    }
  }    
}  

} | Select-Object -property sourcedID, preference | Export-Csv $interimexportedData -NoTypeInformation

## The below re-imports the csv file and renames the header
Import-Csv $interimexportedData |
Select-Object -property sourcedID, @{ expression={$_.preference}; label='title' } |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $exportclasses

## Delete the classesinterim.csv from the folder
Remove-Item $interimexportedData
```

data.csv

```
"sourcedId","title"
9443,"10A/BS1"
9444,"10A/FR1"
10598,"10A/Ft"
9445,"10A/GG1"
9446,"10A/HI1"
9447,"10A/ME1"
9451,"10A/ME2"
9448,"10A/RM1"
9449,"10A/SCTrX"
9452,"10A/SCTrY"
10552,"10A/SOS"
9450,"10A/SP1"
```

exporteddata.csv

```
"sourcedId","title"
"9443","Business Studies - 10A/BS1"
"9444","French - 10A/FR1"
"10598","Form Time - 10A/Ft"
"9445","Geography - 10A/GG1"
"9446","History - 10A/HI1"
"9447","Media Studies - 10A/ME1"
"9451","Media Studies - 10A/ME2"
"9448","Resistant Materials - 10A/RM1"
"9449","Science - 10A/SCTrX"
"9452","Science - 10A/SCTrY"
"10552",""
```

regex.csv

```
"regex_key","preference"
BS,"Business Studies"
FR, "French"
Ar,"Art"
Bt,"Eng & Maths Booster"
Bs,"Business"
Cn,"Construction"
Co,"Computing"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where-Object` to filter out objects with a blank value:

```bsh
$data | Select-Object *,@{Name='preference'; Expression={
  foreach ($p in $patterns) {
    if ($_.title -match $p.'regex_key') {
     $p.preference + " " + "-" + " " + $_.title
     return
    }
  }    
} |Where-Object preference -ne ''
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.  It still shows me the title which was not matched as `""`.  Thanks

Comment: @joko_88 then `Where-Object title -ne ''`